# DefinitelyTyped only showing Namespace

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angular-ui-grid, definitelytyped

I am using typescript in an angular project with ui-grid.  I have installed the DefinitelyTyped file for ui-grid: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/ui-grid/ui-grid.d.ts

In visual studio, my intellisense works for my other d.ts files.  I can see the angular object and all the members.

For this typed file I can only see the namespace: {} uiGrid

Typing uiGrid. shows no members.  Typing a member that I see from the d.ts file manually and the typescript compiler rejects it.

Since all my other typed files are working, is there anything anyone recommends here?

Comment: Did you import it? can you add the line of the import you are doing?

Comment: I have not specifically imported it, because I haven't had to import my other d.ts files to get those to work.

Comment: Do you use namespaces or what module system do you use?And do you have a typings.json file?

Comment: I use just modules and not sure what you mean by module system.  I just regular modules with 'use strict'  I do not have a typings.json file. Haven't needed one so far, so I'm actually not even familiar with that.  EDIT:  I don't have a typings.json file because I'm not using npm typings to install the files.  I'm using nuget.

Comment: do you write `module moduleName { ... }` ? if so you need to use 'import blabla from otherModuleName.Class;` or `import { blalba } from 'otherModuleName'`. Look here: [typescript module system](https://blog.oio.de/2014/01/31/an-introduction-to-typescript-module-system/)

Comment: Yes, I write modules like that.  I haven't had to do that for the other angular typings, so why do I need to do that here?  I went ahead and tried    import UIGrid = uiGrid; and that does not work.

Comment: Sometimes VS gets hick ups when adding new d.ts files...did you try to restart it?

Comment: I restarted VS, yes.  The  odd part is that intellisense does see the namespace, just nothing underneath it.

Comment: Is this the d.ts file you have? [uigrid.d.ts](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/ui-grid/ui-grid.d.ts)

Comment: Correct, the header matches what nuget installed.

Comment: if you write `var a: uiGrid.IBuildColumnsOptions;` and then do `a.` does it give you an error?

Comment: That works fine and I can see intellisense options on a.  But if I try and do anything else with uiGrid in another context, nothing.

Comment: So I dont understand what is the problem you are describing then...Can you put some code?

Comment: The problem is if I type angular. and then hit control space I see a ton of angular members from my angular.d.ts file.  If I do the same with any other typings file, I get the same.  With the ui-grid typigs file I guess it isn't exported the same way as the others to work in my global scope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main difference I can see between uigrid and d.ts like angular is that angular has an exported variable named `angular` of type `IAngularStatic` meaning the angular object has static methods where the uiGrid has no such variable. So when you write `angular.` you are actually seeing all the methods of the interface `IAngularStatic`.

Comment: This looks like the issue, and that the typings just wasn't built in the same convention.